# Asymptotic Notation Implications

Tags: asymptotics

Do the following implications hold,
[image]

I can see that the reverse implication will be true and these implications seem to be true as well, but I can't think of a way to prove or disprove it. Can anyone think of a counter example?

Comment: Please put all relevant info in the question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ implies there exist constants $a$ and $b$ such that
$$a \le \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \le b$$
for all large $n$.

Then,
$$\left|\frac{f(n)-cg(n)}{g(n)}\right| = \left|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} - c\right| \le \max\{|a-c|, |b-c|\} =: C$$
for all large $n$.

---

Counterexample for a):

Let $f(n):= (-1)^n$ and let $g(n)=1$.